# Proof verification for no int solution in cubic

Tags: proof-verification, roots, diophantine-equations, cubics

> $$f(x)=x^3+7x-14(1+n^2)$$Prove there are no integer solutions for any $n\in Z$

My Proof:
Let $A,B,C$ be the three roots of $f(x)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
A+B+C&=0\tag{1}\\
AB+BC+CA&=7\tag{2}\\
ABC&=14(1+n^2)\tag{3}\\
\text{By 1 and 2}, A^2+B^2+C^2&=-14\\
\implies B=\bar{C}&=b+ci\\
\text{Plugging these to (1)}\\
A&=-2b\\
\text{plugging to (2)}\\
c&=\sqrt{3}b\\
\text{plugging to (3)}\\
-4b^3&=7(1+n^2)
\end{align}$$
Which is not possible if $b$ and $n$ are both int due to nature of $mod\space4$

Is this proof valid? Also, Any other better way?

Comment: You can deduce that $x$ is a multiple of 7, divide by 49 to argue that $(1+n^2)/7$ is an integer which is a contradiction as $-1$ is a NQR modulo 7.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is not correct, because it assumes that $b\in\mathbb Z$.

A possible proof is: you can appy [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), with $p=7$, in order to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and therefore that it has no integer roots. This would only fail if $7\mid n^2+1$, but this never happens: $n$ is congruent to $0$, $\pm1$, $\pm2$, or $\pm3$ modulo $7$ and therefore $n^2+1$ is congruent to $1$, $2$, $5$, or $4$ respectively.

Comment: But we must assume that $b\in Z$ if we don't then it automatically doesn't have any int solutions

Comment: Also, I think the purpose of this question was to reach the criterion and not use it directly. This is for undergrad entrance

Comment: @AFalseName I suppose that the question is to know if **some** root is integer, not if **all** roots are integer.

Comment: the question is prove there are no int solution for $f(x)$